# Difficulty in understanding cantor normal form

Tags: set-theory, definition, ordinals

Cantors normal form of x is defined as the following
$x = \omega^{a_1} n_1 + \dots + \omega^{a_k} n_k$, Where $x$ is an ordinal and where $\langle a_i \rangle$ is a strictly decreasing finite sequence of ordinals, $\langle n_i \rangle$ is a finite sequence of ordinals and $k\in \Bbb N$.

My problem in the understanding of the cantor normal form is the fact that i don't understand why one can write any finite ordinal in terms of cantors normal form, and why each ordinal has a unique cantor normal form.

Comment: You want $n_i<\omega$.

Comment: Any _finite_ ordinal can be written as a single term of the form $\omega^0\cdot n$. The point of Cantor normal form is that it can also represent _infinite_ ordinals up to $\varepsilon_0$.

Comment: @Henning Not just those. If $x>\varepsilon_0$, you can no longer ensure that $a_1<x $, but any nonzero ordinal admits a Cantor normal form.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo: Right, but I think it is arguable whether the Cantor normal form is then a _representation_ of the ordinal we're looking at. Certainly it ceases to be an ordinal _notation_ at that point.

Comment: @Henning Sure, but the Cantor normal form is used in many different situations in set theory. Its use as ordinal notation is perhaps its best known, but far from its main, application.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo: OK, so I agree I shouldn't have said, "_The_ point".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, prove that the map $\alpha\mapsto\omega^\alpha $ is normal, that is, strictly increasing and continuous at limits. Use this to show that for any $\alpha $ there is a least $\beta $ such that $\alpha <\omega^\beta $, and that, if $\alpha\ne0$, then this least $\beta $ is a successor ordinal, say $\beta=\beta_0+1$.

This shows that, for $\alpha\ne0$, there is a unique $\beta_0$ such that $\omega^{\beta_0}\le\alpha <\omega^{\beta_0+1}=\omega^{\beta_0}\cdot\omega $. Conclude from this that there is a unique positive integer $n_0 $ such that $\omega^{\beta_0}\cdot n_0\le \alpha <\omega^{\beta_0}\cdot (n_0+1) $.

Conclude from the above that there is a unique $\gamma <\omega^{\beta_0} $ such that $\alpha=\omega^{\beta_0}\cdot n_0+\gamma $. Now argue inductively, with $\gamma $ in place of $\alpha $.

The argument shows existence of the normal form. Uniqueness follows easily as well: Given two potential representations of $\alpha $, check that they are equal term by term by contradiction, considering the first term from left to right where they disagree.